# Apache Ignite - google Image download link is broken

Tags: ignite

I am trying to download the image for **Apache Ignite Google Image** from the link stated below, and it seems to be broken.

Are there any other sources to connect Google Cloud Portal to Apache Ignite?

> - **<kbd>[`https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/google-compute-deployment`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/google-compute-deployment)</kbd>**
> - **Code/command:**

```
gcloud compute images create ignite-image --source-uri gs://ignite-media/ignite-google-image.tar.gz
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - The resource 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/ignite-media/o/ignite-google-image.tar.gz' of type 'Google Cloud Storage object' was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting, the image has been recovered and available under the original URL:
https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-media/ignite-google-image.tar.gz